# How to set a wallpaper for apps in full screen (in Yosemite and higher)

Tags: fullscreen, macos

Some apps, like Terminal and Textmate, offer transparent windows. With a good wallpaper, this can look really great.

But apps in full screen mode have a black background, not your wallpaper.

Is there a hidden feature or setting to set the background of fullscreen apps to a wallpaper?

Comment: This will cause most apps to crash

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like there's a safe way of doing this; looking at [this Apple Support Discussion answer](https://discussions.apple.com/message/17032574#17032574), I can still find the referenced background image in my Yosemite install at:

`/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/Resources/NSTexturedFullScreenBackgroundColor.png`

Since this is buried in /System, it's highly unlikely there's .plist file/attribute you could change to point to an alternative background – so you would need to replace this image file with another to change the background. As you may or may not know, editing anything within the /System directory is tempting super-bad juju and **very, very, very strongly discouraged** by Apple and any IT people worth their salt.

Personally, I would recommend that if you really want a window background image in these apps that you instead configure each app to use the background image and dispense with the transparency (or submit a feature request to Apple and embrace the restriction in the meantime).